# 2012 Ford Escape grinding noise while braking

Tags: ford, brakes, escape

My Ford Escape started making an unusual noise recently.  Would appreciate if anyone can help me diagnose the problem.

- The noise only occurs when I brake and only when my speed gets down to about 15 mph or less
- It's a grinding, crunching sort of sound
- It's a repeated "crunch" "crunch" "crunch" as if something on the axel rubs against something else every time it rotates
- It happens regardless of the weather
- It sounds like it's either coming from my back passenger tire or both back tires

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: Have you checked the rear pads?

Comment: Is your Escape 2wd or 4wd?

Comment: Also, pull up your parking brake just *one click*, then drive the vehicle (a very short distance) and see if it still occurs.

Comment: @Paulster2 it's 2wd

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things it could be.

1. Dirt in the brake drums (if its not rear disc)
2. Pads or shoes have been damaged or become worn
3. Hardware has come loose and is getting caught as you are braking
4. Rusted drums or discs

You should get this check out right away before it causes expensive damage or you loose braking ability all together.

Comment: I tried all of the above -- **that is not the problem**.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you have your own question, please ask it in a new question. Comments to answers to another person's question is not how to get help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a rhythmic noise which repeats regularly, but slows down as the car slows down, first I'd look for a warped disc or drum.